# datagrid rows to save in collection and show on another page asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, collections, datatable, rows

I have grid in my page which have four columns with multiple rows
Userid username stateid and statename

which collection i should use to send data to another page using session
my code is

```
string[] strArray = new string[] {}; 

        foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvCompany.Rows)
        {
           strArray =new string[4] {new[] {gr.Cells[0].Text}.ToString(), new[] {gr.Cells[1].Text}.ToString(), new[] {gr.Cells[2].Text}.ToString(),new[] {gr.Cells[3].Text}.ToString()};


        }
        Session["List"] = strArray;
        Response.Redirect("Tid.aspx?Mode=List");
```

on tid page my code is

```
string[] ls = new string[] { }; 
                  ls =(string[]) Session["List"];
                foreach (string st in ls )
                {
                    //get each cell
                }
```

but value of st is system.string rather than value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an string[] is not recommended since the more fields will add in future the difficult it will get to keep the field and index relationship bug free..

You can create a proper class object eg. Company and pass a List to other class, List is in System.Collections.Generic namespace.